# Javascript Slider with Multiple Allowed sections/timeslots

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider, timeslots

I want to implement a time-slot selector in jquery/javascript slider form.

There are a few slider libraries out there such as Ion Slider, jQRangeSlider etc. but I don't know how I would be going about this. It doesn't look like they support multiple "dead-zones".

I want the user to be able to select a timeslot (from and to) during a particular day. To select the day, I have implemented a date picker, then for the date, I retrieve the already occupied slots for instance:

```
07h00 - Available
07h30 - Available
08h00 - Occupied
08h30 - Occupied
09h00 - Occupied
09h30 - Available
...
18h30 - Available
19h00 - Available
```

So the range picker must look like this:
[image]

The user should only be able to select a time zone in the available sections (blue) and drag the start slider between the "available" section, and the end selector will move along with it. There might be multiple unavailable zones (Red).

Is this possible with the libraries already out there or is this a case of roll my own?

I have thought about using a bunch of check boxes then check all the boxes between the start and end time-slots, and disable the already occupied slots, but I think a slider like this would be much more user friendly to use, functionally and visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to implement an ionRangeSlider with custom slots from `05h30` to `19h30`. A separate array of `used` time-slots to which I compare in the `onChange` event.

```
var slider = $("#timeslotSlider").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    from: 1,
    from_value: "06h00",
    to: 2,
    to_value: "06h30",
    values: timeslotvalues,
    onChange: function (data) {
        timeslotSetSelectedText(data);
    }
});

var sliderdata = slider.data("ionRangeSlider");
var dt = sliderdata.result.from_value != null ? sliderdata.result : sliderdata.options;

timeslotSetSelectedText(dt);
```

The `timeslotSetSelectedText` function compares the selected range to the `used` slots then display a message `"Available"` or `"Overlaps Existing time-slot"`

The same function is used to `Validate` the selected slot before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

A double slider can be made with very little effort by overlaying two sliders on top of each other using CSS. You need to listen to the onchange events of these two and reset the slider to previous value or closet non dead region when set to a dead region.

```js
var deadZones = [[2,3], [6,7]];
function showVal(input) {
    deadZones.forEach(([from, to]) => {
      // reset to old value if in dead zone
      if(from <= input.value && input.value <= to)
        input.value = input.oldValue;
    });
  input.oldValue = input.value;
  //console.log(input.id, input.value);
  displayValues();
}

function displayValues() {
  var a = $('#a').val();
  var b = $('#b').val();
  $('#slider-values').text(`Min: ${Math.min(a,b)} Max: ${Math.max(a,b)}`);
}
displayValues();
```

```css
html,body{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
#a, #b{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
#b {
  top: 60px;
}

/* from: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/ */
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  width: 90%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
  background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
  margin-left: 5%;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
automatic */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; /* Add cool effects to your sliders! */
  position: relative;
}
input[type=range]#a::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   top: 100px;
}
input[type=range]#b::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   top: 70px;
}

.slider-bg {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 135px;
}
.slider-bg div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.slider-bg div.disabled {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="a" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" oninput="showVal(this)" onchange="showVal(this)" />
<input id="b" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="9" oninput="showVal(this)" onchange="showVal(this)"/>
<hr />
<div class="slider-bg">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="disabled">2</div>
  <div class="disabled">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div class="disabled">6</div>
  <div class="disabled">7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
<div id="slider-values"></div>
```